# How to pass data into a useState modal

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, state, react-bootstrap

I'm attempting to have an icon's state change depending on whether or not there's data present. For example, if the 'Likes' counter is greater than 0 than the circle will be filled in, otherwise, it will be an empty circle.

I have not been able to figure out how to render this via useState

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ActivityIconEngaged from "./ActivityIconEngaged";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import data from "../Assets/ActivityData";
import { faCircle } from "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

class ActivityIcon extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activities: data.activities,
      activity: data.activities[0]
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { activities, activity } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {activities.map(activity => (
          <ActivityIconData key={activity._id} activity={activity} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function ActivityIconData({ activity }) {
  const { index, likeCount } = activity;
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setShow(false);
  };

  const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState({ showContent: true });
  const showContent = trigger;

  const openModal = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShow(true);
  };

  if ({ likeCount } > 0) {
    setTrigger(!trigger);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div id={`activity-${index}`}>
        <span onClick={openModal} className="mr-1">
          {showContent ? (
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faCircle}
              size="2x"
              className="ActivityIconDefault"
            />
          ) : (
            <ActivityIconEngaged />
          )}
        </span>

        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Activity</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>likes: {likeCount}</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
              Save Changes
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

ActivityIconData.propTypes = {
  activity: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default ActivityIcon;
```

The result that I'm currently getting is that the modal successfully opens when the circle is clicked, HOWEVER, the circle is not filled when the number of likes exceeds 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're declaring too many pieces of state to handle this.  You don't need a `likeCount` as well as a `trigger` variable with a `showContent` property.

If you want to use a ternary operator to show the icon, you can just replace `showContent` with an expression for `likeCount`:

```
{likeCount > 0 ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} size="2x" className="ActivityIconDefault" /> : <ActivityIconEngaged />}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that helps out tremendously. The primary reason that I had showContent in there was because I'd like to add additional functionality to the state. For instance, with the edits that you suggested how would I go about changing the state to an empty circle once the modal is opened?

Comment: Happy to help!  If the functionality is all determined by the number of likes, you can plug that expression in anywhere its needed, if not you'd need more data to determine conditions for it, but I'd recommend using that as directly as possible as well to help keep things easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

In first look, your condition is always false because you making a [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) between `object` and a `number`.

> Two distinct objects are never equal for either strict or abstract comparisons.

```js
// instead of { likeCount } > 0, which always results false
if (likeCount > 0) {
  setTrigger(!trigger);
}
```